# Let $\varphi:\left(a,b \right)\rightarrow R$ twice derivatible with $\varphi\left(a \right)=\varphi\left(b \right)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\varphi:\left(a,b \right)\rightarrow R$ twice derivatible with $\varphi\left(a \right)=\varphi\left(b \right)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ and ${\varphi}^{(2)}(x)>0$ Prove that $\varphi\left(x \right)<0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

how ${\varphi}^{(2)}(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ we have ${\varphi}^{(1)}$ is strictly decreasing, by the rolle theorem, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that  ${\varphi}^{(1)}(c)=0$,  As ${\varphi}^{(1)}$ is strictly decreasing in $(a, b)$ and ${\varphi}^{(1)}(c)=0$, so ${\varphi}^{(1)}<0$ in $[a,c)$ and ${\varphi}^{(1)}>0$ in $(c,b]$.

Is this conclusion right?

As ${\varphi}^{(1)}$ is strictly decreasing in $(a, b)$ and ${\varphi}^{(1)}(c)=0$, so ${\varphi}^{(1)}<0$ in $[a,c)$ and ${\varphi}^{(1)}>0$ in $(c,b]$.

Comment: $f''>0\implies f'$ is strictly increasing. And to apply Rolle's theorem you need that $f'$ takes the same value at two points, which is impossible as it is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 3):

You can conclude like this: $\phi'<0$ in $[a,c)$ implies that $\phi$ strictly decreases on $[a,c]$ for every $x\in [a,c], \phi(x)<\phi(a)=0$. On the other hand, you have $\phi$ strictly increases on $[c,b]$, and if $x\in[c,b], \phi(x)<\phi(b)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

It follows by assumptions that $f$ is a  strictly convex function. Since for each $x\in (a,b)$ there exists a $t\in (0,1)$ such that $x=ta+(1-t)b$, then by the convexity of $f$ we have
$$
f(x)< tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)=0.
$$

Comment: Another way of writing would be, how ${\varphi}^{(2)}(x)>0 $ ,${\varphi}$ Is strictly convex in $[a, b]$, that is, $\forall x\in (a, b)$ \\ $a<x<b \Rightarrow \varphi(x)<\varphi(a)+\frac{\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$\\$Rightarrow \varphi(x)<0$

Answer (score -1):

If $\varphi''(x)>0$ $\forall x\in (a,b)$ then $\varphi'(x)$ is strictly incresing on $(a,b).$ Now:

- Is it possible to have $\varphi'>0?$ In such a case $\varphi$ will be sctrictly increasing and thus $\varphi(b)>\varphi(a).$ Contradiction.
- Is it possible to have $\varphi'<0?$ In such a case $\varphi$ will be sctrictly decreasing and thus $\varphi(b)<\varphi(a).$ Contradiction.

Thus, we have that there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $\varphi'<0$ on $(a,c),$ $\varphi'(c)=0$ and $\varphi'>0$ on $(c,b).$

Can you conclude?